# SQL Query to get distinct results from one table and match those results to the another column in the table

Tags: sql, tree, distinct-values

I have an SQL table with product names in one column and a product category in another column. So each product belongs to a specific category.  I am trying to figure out an sql command that will return distinct values from the product name column but will also display the product category each product belongs to. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please tag the database you are using?
Also could you please provide some sample data? Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `select name, category from products` ???

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
  SELECT Distinct([ProductName]),[ProductCategeory] FROM [DB].[dbo].[tblProduct]
```